# React does not see css properties

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The issue here is that when I use build-in tags such as "form-group" in this case, the CSS styling is not applied in the browser. If I put my own definitions, such as "classes.form" the the browser will see CSS. But when I use built-in, the CSS is not visible.

When I go to inspect, it shows me styles for .form-group.scss. But not my own css.

I have the following code. The build-in tag, in this case, is "form-group".

```
<div className="form-group">
   <label htmlFor="email"></label>
    <Input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="email"
      value={email}
      onChange={onChangeEmail}
      validations={[required, validEmail]}
    />
</div>
```

My css:

```
.form-group {
margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
margin-top: 0.2rem;
}
```

Comment: Browsers don't have built-in styles for any class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such things as built-in classes.

`form-group` is a [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) (CSS framework) class, so you should install bootstrap first to get these.

npm: `npm install bootstrap`

yarn: `yarn add bootstrap`

In your index.js file, make sure you `import` Bootstrap:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Now you should be able to use the `form-group` className.

If you want to apply your own CSS next to the Bootstrap CSS, you could create the class like you did but give it a different name like this:

```css
.form-group-margin {
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
}
```

And apply it combined with the bootstrap class like this:

```html
<div className="form-group form-group-margin">
   <label htmlFor="email"></label>
    <Input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="email"
      value={email}
      onChange={onChangeEmail}
      validations={[required, validEmail]}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: I do have it installed. It does show the form. The problem here is that the styling itself is not applied to .form-group in the css file.

Comment: Try picking a different name for the class like .form-group-margin and say `className="form-group form-group-margin"`, that way you will apply the bootstrap class and your own defined class

Comment: Thank you for the accept, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

This may be a silly suggestion but have you tried appending !important to your styles?

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem !important;
  margin-top: 0.2rem !important;
}
```

`!important` should override the default styles and use what you passed in for the margins.

Also here is an example of this in action.

[image: Edit stoic-grothendieck-gbvxk]

Answer (score -1):

Try to set height and width and apply other styling to div. Also remove default styling from browser.

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
```